# Array supports values of any type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray

As per swift doc - 
“An array stores values of the same type in an ordered list.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/in/jEUH0.l

```
var justBlankArray = []
var a:Int = 4
var b:Dictionary = ["Address":"Silver Oaks"]
justBlankArray = ["Tush",a,b] 
println(justBlankArray[0].classForCoder)
println(justBlankArray[1].classForCoder)
println(justBlankArray[2].classForCoder)
```

Output-

> NSString
>       NSNumber
>       NSDictionary

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Are they not of different type in a array?

Comment: blank array takes anyObject..if you define any type in array than it takes that type only

Comment: Thanks a lot got it!

Answer (score 0):

Created `justBlankArray` is `NSArray`-type, which is not Swift-type `Array`. If you want to store any type of objects in Swift-type `Array`, you can do that:

```
var justBlankArray : [AnyObject] = []
```

It creates an array which can hold any type of object. Even C-structs, what `NSArray` cannot.

Comment: Look what NSArray does -     NSArray *arr = @[@"String",@5,@{@"name": @"tush"}];

yes it considers anyobject in that case.

Comment: And what is your concern regarding my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the array like:

```
var justBlankArray = []
```

The type will be `NSArray`, NSArray can hold heterogeneous data. (Means it can hold any object)

If you print the class of the `justBlankArray` using:

```
println(justBlankArray.classForCoder)
```

It'll give you `NSArray` as result.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a type for array literal it is inferred as `NSArray`. `NSArray` can hold any type of class objects (`AnyObject`).

[image]